# C++ class redefinition error help

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, redefinition

I am getting errors like:

```
FxMathFunctions.h: In function 'FxInt32 IMin(FxInt32, FxInt32)':

FxMathFunctions.h:13: error: redefinition of 'FxInt32 IMin(FxInt32, FxInt32)'

FxMathFunctions.h:15: error: 'FxInt32 IMin(FxInt32, FxInt32)' previously defined here
```

In FxMathFunctions.h I have:

```
11: struct FxPoint2d;
12:
13: inline FxInt32 IMin(FxInt32 i1,FxInt32 i2)
14: {
15:    if (i2 < i1) i1 = i2;
16:    return i1;
17: }
```

FxInt32 is defined in a header that I am including as:

```
typedef long                FxInt32;
```

I cant decide by the errors if it says that FxInt32 is being redefined or if the whole function is.

How do I solve this?

UPDATE I added the line numbers above.

Comment: What's on lines 13 and 15 of FxMathFunctions.h?

Comment: That's very odd. It looks like the line numbers got shifted down a bit somehow. What's on line 11-12?

Comment: @bdonlan - updated again

Answer (score 1):

It's saying the whole function is defined twice.

My psychic debugging powers tell me you are somehow recursively including that header, and that header doesn't have a proper guard against this happening. Thus the inline function is defined twice.

Comment: Weird - why would the reported line numbers be shifted then?

Comment: I have a header guard in place and to be sure, I changed the name of it. #pragma once as well

Answer (score 0):

Move the function definition into a .cpp file and just have
the prototype in the .h file. Let the compiler worry about the optimization

Comment: To do this, I would not using inline in the .cpp, correct? and how would I change to put the prototype in the .h? The use of inline confuses me, dont I just remove it since I am moving the code into the .cpp?

Comment: Yes, no need for inline in the .cpp file. The inline keyword is a directive telling the compiler to copy the whole function implementation instead of just calling the function. Just remove the inline, put FxInt32 IMin(FxInt32 i1,FxInt32 i2); in your header and the definition in the .cpp file and you are good to go. The typedef you should place in the header as well of course.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing what's on lines 13 and 15 of FxMathFunctions.h. That said, keep in mind that C++ has a built-in [`std::min`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min/) and [`std::max`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/) in `<algorithm>`, and they work for all comparable types.

Comment: Thanks, let me look into these.

Comment: Added links to the documentation for you